# how does bastion know which rds instance to connect to in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to set up a bastion host in AWS in order to perform administrative options on an RDS instance in a private subnet. I am following the instructions from the official documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/step1.html), but there it is not clear how the bastion will know which RDS instance to connect to. How would I make sure that it can 'talk to' my intended RDS? (as far as I understand, the key pair is just something I can create anytime and enter to connect to the bastion itself, but not the RDS, or am I wrong?)

Comment: The bastion won't know which RDS instance to connect to. You will. Supply the relevant endpoint of the RDS instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked uses an AWS CloudFormation stack to deploy the Bastion. I'm not sure exactly what configuration it is using, so my answer will be generic, rather than applying to this specific situation.

The normal configuration is:

- A database in a private subnet
- A Bastion server (EC2 instance) in a public subnet
- A connection is made to the Bastion, which then allows an on-connection to the database

There are a number of ways of connecting to the database *through* the Bastion. Here's one that I use:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@BASTION-IP -L 3306:DATABASE-DNS-NAME:3306
```

This tells the SSH connection to forward any traffic sent to my local port 3306 (the first number), through the SSH connection, but then send it to `DATABASE-DNS-NAME:3306` (the database server). Any response from the database will come back the same way.

Then, when I wish to refer to the database from my computer, I reference:

```
localhost:3306
```

It *appears* that the database is on my own computer, but the traffic is actually sent across SSH to the Bastion, then onto the database.

There are newer and better ways of doing this forwarding that other people might (hopefully) add as a comment or another answer, but this is the way I make my connections through a Bastion.

**Fun fact:** A *Bastion* is the bit of a castle wall that sticks out, allowing defenders to shoot arrows at attackers attempting to climb the wall. In a similar way, the Bastion Server *sticks out* into the Internet, beyond the protected part of the network.

Comment: Tried this approach as I have a similar issue, got this error:

bind [127.0.0.1]:3306: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3306
Could not request local forwarding.